# Why does urllib.parse.quote encode non reserved characters in urls?

Tags: python, urllib, url-encoding, quote, reserved

The `parse` function in `urllib.parse` can be used to encode url components. But its behavior is different from the standard javascript encoder.

In python

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.parse.quote('(a+b)')
... '%28a%2Bb%29'
```

in Javascript

```
>>> encodeURIComponent('(a+b)')
... "(a%2Bb)"
```

Why is the python function more "strict" when encoding the url component?

If I understood it right, brackets are not reserved characters in urls. So I don't understand why they are escaped in the urllib parse function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html), brackets are [reserved](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-2.2).

By [default](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote), Python will percent-encode every character passed to `quote()` except for `_.-/`. However, `quote()` is tunable. If you want strict RFC 3986 behavior, set `safe` to `'~'`:

```
urllib.parse.quote(string, safe='~')
```

If you want to minimally match javascript-on-your-platform's behavior that you showed (you didn't state which parts of which ECMAScript standard it conforms to):

```
urllib.parse.quote(string, safe='()')
```